# How do I get the most updated data from the database based on the entry date for various entry ID that is multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables, namely CALCULATED INPUT, RAW MATERIAL INPUT and COMPANY

```
select * from [LTBU_MKT_RAW_CALULATED_DATA] e 
inner join
(select t2.COMPANY_ENTRY_ID, t2.ENTRY_ID from LTBU_MKT_RAW_MAT_INPUT as t2) b on b.ENTRY_ID = e.ENTRY_ID 
inner join
(select h.[COMPANY],h.[GUID]  from LTBU_MKT_COMPANY as h) g on b.COMPANY_ENTRY_ID = g.GUID 


(Select c.COMPANY,Max(t1.ENTRY_DATE) as MaxDate
from  [inet].[dbo].[LTBU_MKT_RAW_CALULATED_DATA]  t1 
inner join
(select t2.COMPANY_ENTRY_ID, t2.ENTRY_ID from LTBU_MKT_RAW_MAT_INPUT as t2) b on b.ENTRY_ID = t1.ENTRY_ID 
inner join

(select t3.[COMPANY],t3.[GUID]  from LTBU_MKT_COMPANY as t3) c on b.COMPANY_ENTRY_ID = c.GUID
inner join
(SELECT t2.ENTRY_ID,t2.CHEMICAL_NAME,t2.CHEMICAL_QTY_KG,t2.CHMEICAL_CAL_PRICE,t2.CHMEICAL_PROCESS from  [inet].[dbo].[LTBU_MKT_RAW_CALULATED_DATA] as t2) a on a.ENTRY_ID = t1.ENTRY_ID
group by c.COMPANY)
```

But it not able to combine all the information due to the MAX(ENTRY_Date)

Any help or comments is appreciated.

Comment: Please use the code format option of the question editor.

Comment: add GROUP BY  c.Company

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function in the order by. Something like...

```
order by row_number() over (partition by ENTRY_ID order by ENTRY_Date desc)
```

I’m not sure which ENTRY_ID you want to use since more than one table has it. Be sure you reference it accordingly.